# visually select datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to use a datagridview as a "tag" mesh.  I have a number of objects that I want to set and edit "tags" for.  Each cell in the datagridview has a string tag in it, the datagridview is multi-select, so the user can select a whole lot of tags.

It works great for setting tags...

However, I want to be able to edit them.  So, when I load the datagridview, I want to programatically select the cells corresponding to the existing tags.

Code is quite straight forward:

```
public frmSaveQuery(string Name, string Description, string tagList, List<TagType> AllTags)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TagList = AllTags;
        Cancelled = true;
        txtQueryName.Text = Name;
        txtDescription.Text = Description;
        string[] tags = tagList.Split(new string[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tagSelector.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (tags.Contains(cell.Value.ToString().ToUpper()))
                {
                    cell.Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tagSelector.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Selected) Debug.WriteLine (cell.Value.ToString());

            }
        }

    }
```

The debug verifies that the cells are "selected".  However, on the actual datagridview, they don't visually look like selected cells (i.e. not highlighted blue).

Any idea how to make them look visually selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before controls are displayed you cannot set focus to them.
Event handler of `Shown` event is good place for this. This event raised only once when form displayed first time ([MSDN Form.Shown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You only need save `tags` values from `tagList` in the variable for later using in the `Shown` eventhandler

```
private String[] _Tags;

public frmSaveQuery(string Name, 
                    string Description, 
                    string tagList, 
                    List<TagType> AllTags)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TagList = AllTags;
    Cancelled = true;
    txtQueryName.Text = Name;
    txtDescription.Text = Description;

    //Save tags in the class variable
    _Tags = tagList.Split(new string[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //Wiring up handler to the event
    this.Shown += frmSaveQuery_Shown;
}


public void frmSaveQuery_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_Tags == null || _Tags.Length == 0)
        return;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tagSelector.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (tags.Contains(cell.Value.ToString().ToUpper()))
            {
                cell.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tagSelector.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Selected) Debug.WriteLine (cell.Value.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```